# Creating list of pandas.Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am use a vectorize code to create a list of pandas.Intervals.

Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 5, 10])
b = np.array([3, 8, 12])
```

Desired output:

[image]

What I have tried:

A:

```
pd.Intervals(a,b)
```

B:

```
df['c'] = tuple(np.array([a, b]).T)
df['c'] = df['c'].astype(pd.Intervals)
```

Comment: `pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays`

`pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays.html#pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays

Comment: @llan12 if you're working with intervals in pandas check out `piso` https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Can you help me to find reference to operations on pandas series of intervals?
(For example, for series of datetime64, I use series.dt.[operation])

Edit: well you already did, but if you know something from pandas docs that would be appreciated , thanks!

Comment: you will find the IntervalIndex and IntervalArray methods in the pandas doc I linked in the first comment.  I don't believe there are any accessors (like dt or str etc) on `pandas.Series` for interval methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Riley reference to find the solution:
using [pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays.html#pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays)

The solution:

```
a = np.array([1, 5, 10])
b = np.array([3, 8, 12])
c = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IntervalIndex` instead of `IntervalArray` to have more methods:

```
c = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(a, b)
print(c)

# Output:
IntervalIndex([(1, 3], (5, 8], (10, 12]], dtype='interval[int64, right]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 5, 10])
b = np.array([3, 8, 12])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': a, 
    'b': b, 
    'c': [pd.Interval(*boundaries) for boundaries in zip(a, b)]
})

print(df)
```

Result:

```
    a   b         c
0   1   3    (1, 3]
1   5   8    (5, 8]
2  10  12  (10, 12]
```

Comment: this solution is not vectorize